# How to set Xcode plugin for code auto formatting

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am searching for a plugin to auto format objective-c code within XCode, it would also be very helpful to have a set of optional styling formats,

I'm aiming to follow Google's code convention: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml as a start, any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://objclean.com is a new tool that looks like what you need.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

***updated April 2013***

As Roger Nolan and rcw3 suggested, you can go a lot further with [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net).  The latest release version can be download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uncrustify/files/uncrustify/).

---

### Integration Into Xcode

Integration into Xcode is dependent upon the version of Xcode that is installed.

- **Xcode 4.6 & newer**

Benoît Bourdon's [BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode)

This plugin provides access to Uncrustify right from Xcode's "Edit" menu ("Uncrustify Selected Files", "Uncrustify Active File", and "Uncrustify Selected Lines").  Just build the project and the plugin is compiled and installed.

As of April 2, 2013, Uncrustify 0.60 and an Uncrustify configuration file are include with the plugin.  To use a custom Uncrustify configuration file, make sure to read the section titled "How to customize the Uncrustify configuration?" of [README.md](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode/blob/master/README.md).

*Note: To use Uncrustify from the command line, for example as part of a git hook, I recommend building and installing [Uncrustify](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uncrustify/files/uncrustify/) independently.  For consistency sake, I also recommend replacing the version of Uncrustify that comes with the plugin with a link to the version Uncrustify that was independently built and installed.  The following is how to do that:*

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/UncrustifyPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/Resources
mv uncrustify uncrustify.orig
ln -s /usr/local/bin/uncrustify uncrustify
```

- **Xcode 4.x**

Jonah Williams' [Code Formatting in Xcode 4](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/10/code-formatting-in-xcode-4/)

- **Xcode 3.x**

Jonah Williams' [Code Formatting in Xcode](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/08/07/code-formatting-in-xcode/)

---

### Example Uncrustify Configuration File

The Uncrustify 0.60 configuration file that I use for Objective-C is located [here](https://gist.github.com/m2orris/5297267).

---

### Update the Uncrustify Configuration File for a New Version of Uncrustify

To update the Uncrustify configuration file for a new version of Uncrustify, start a Terminal and type:

```
mv uncrustify.cfg uncrustify.cfg.old
uncrustify -c uncrustify.cfg.old --update-config > uncrustify.cfg
```

To see the changes made to the Uncrustify configuration, in the terminal type:

```
diff uncrustify.cfg.old uncrustify.cfg
```

---

### To View a Documented Version of the Uncrustify Configuration File

To view a documented version of the Uncrustify configuration file, start a Terminal and type:

```
uncrustify -c uncrustify.cfg --show-config
```

Comment: After trying on it, it seems very very good. @mmorris, do you have any  updated uncrustify_obj_c.cfg file?

Comment: @LiangWang Take supplied configuration from the answer and then run `uncrustify` with the `--update-config` option (explained in the answer). `sort` both versions of the configuration file. `diff` the sorted configuration files.  The `diff` output highlights the new configuration options.  Run `uncrustify` with `--show-config` to look up the new configuration options.  Update the new configuration file with any desired changes.

Comment: I prefer uncrustify as a system service so that it's usable everywhere (TextEdit, BBEdit, etc.!) and you can assign it a global hotkey (command-option-control-I). I just used Automator to create a "Run Shell Script" workflow: "/usr/local/bin/uncrustify -q -c /usr/local/share/uncrustify/uncrustify.cfg -l OC+" with 'Service receives selected "text"' and check 'output replaces selected text'. Then put the workflow in your '~/Library/Services/' folder.

Comment: The link to the Example Uncrustify 0.60 config is broken.

Comment: @dbainbridge The link to the Example Uncrustify 0.60 config has been restored.

Answer (score 8):

XCode has a code formatter built in - it's a little basic but can re-indent your code. First set your indentation preferences in Xcode ([as mouviciel suggests](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertools/conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/100-The_Text_Editor/chapter_5_section_12.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002679-SW64)). Then select the source you want to reintend and choose Edit | Format | Re-indent.

If you want to go further, Hackertoys has instructions for [adding uncrustify support](http://hackertoys.com/2008/09/18/adding-a-code-beautifier-script-to-xcode/) to Xcode. I have not tried this.

Answer (score 3):

AppCode from Jetbrains has a very good code formatter. For my taste uncrustify feels much too hacky.

Answer (score 2):

After tinkering with multiple external formatters and the weak internal xcode formatter, I finally settled with uncrustify.  Uncrustify has fairly good Objective-C support, can easily be integrated with xcode as a user script, and provides a centralized formatter for pretty much all languages that xcode natively supports.

The biggest hurdle with xcode is the daunting configuration file.  My recommendation, take one of the supplied sample configs (ben2.cfg is very good), merge in the objc.cfg sample, and tweak as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Reportedly, [bcpp](http://invisible-island.net/bcpp/bcpp.html) works just fine on obj-c, and it has a [TextMate](http://blog.neontology.com/posts/2007/01/05/beautiful-c-in-textmate) plugin, too.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer is that some little things can be set from within Xcode, as 2-space indents. See [Indentation Preferences](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertools/conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/100-The_Text_Editor/chapter_5_section_12.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002679-SW64) in Xcode Workspace Guide.