# Is there an Uncrustify config for Google's Objective-C style?

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

Is there a config file for [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) that will format Objective-C per [Google's Objective-C style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml)?

Example config files for Uncrustify [look a bit daunting](https://gist.github.com/841452) and I'm hoping that I won't need to build one from scratch...

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to incorporate uncrustify into my automated builds but faced problems. I found an alternative that I'm happy with. The AppCode objective-C IDE from Jetbrains works as a supplemental IDE to Xcode.

It includes an excellent and highly configurable code formatting tool, among other things.

[image]

. . . to my knowledge you can't invoke this tool from the cmd-line, however I've just filed a feature request to do so.

If you prefer Uncrustify there's a [GUI Tool](https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UncrustifyX) that might help.

Comment: Great find, it is much easier to see what will happen when the code gets re-formatted this way. The preview area (visible at the right in the screenshot) shows the effect of each option when checked or unchecked.

Comment: Since I answered that there's also uncrusifyX https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UncrustifyX

Comment: It should be noted that while AppCode has reformatting capability, it doesn't have a 'Google Style' profile built in.  I can't see any way of generic import/export of profiles.  The default is also almost useless in that it does virtually nothing.  You have to go in and make quite a few changes (lots of tedious experimentation) before you get much useful happening.

Comment: You're right - I could see a save option, but nothing about importing. . I've raised a feature request with Jetbrains.

Comment: I think the .idea/codeStyleSettings.xml file may be helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

That config file seems daunting only in length... (I've seen much worse!) I don't know if it conforms to the Google style guide, but `mmorris` posted his .cfg in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321776/18961

You don't want to strictly conform to the Google style anyway... it only uses two character indentation!  ;)

Comment: 4 char indents are insane, especially for posting code on the web! 2 should more than suffice IMHO.