# Is there any software to format source code for C/C++ on Mac?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C style formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561474/objective-c-style-formatter)

I have wrote a program and wonder if there is any software to format the codes the way it should look like a good programmer?

I know I shouldn't rely on it but just for my curiosity and to have this done in a better way because my code it so mess up and I want it look nicer and better.

On mac would be appreciated if not PC would be okay.

Comment: Can you explain what you're after in more detail? What do you want this software to do?

Comment: There's no software that will make you a better programmer (unless it's an ebook reader program with an O'Reilly book open in it...). Are you asking for a code *formatting* tool?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta sorry I didn't explain it well, I've wrote a program but my indentation is so mess up and I want it to look better the way a good programmer should manage it.

Comment: @Borealid really sorry for my bad English, that's what I meant for code formatting tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using XCode, you can re-indent your files (Editor -> Structure -> Re-Indent), or with the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Great thanks I never know that, very useful :D

Answer (score 4):

One nice code formatter is astyle. The download link can be found [here](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/). And I just checked, they support Mac as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's the command-line program `indent`, which does not do complete style formatting but does get indentation sorted out for you. `indent` should come with your Mac (or maybe it comes with Xcode? not sure). See `man indent`.